# My "blur" function doesn't work correctly

Tags: c

My program applies filters  to pictures and one of the filters I've been practising was the "blur" filter using the "blur box" which works by taking each pixel and, for each color value, giving it a new value by averaging the color values of neighboring pixels(within 1 row and column of the original pixel (forming a 3x3 box)). But not always so for example for the pixels in corner it won't be a 3x3 box but a 2x2 box also for the pixels on edges it will be a 3x2 box. And for that i've made a function called "blur" to do this. But even though the filter applied successfully after running my program, it stills show me this error message:

:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
expected "127 140 149\n", not "145 160 169\n"

:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
expected "80 95 105\n", not "90 106 116\n"

:) blur correctly filters pixel in corner

:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n90 1..."

:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n90 1..."

Seems that there is a problem with the color values, I tried many things to fix it but none of them worked

and this is my program:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // iterate over image pixels
    for ( int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for ( int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            //initialize variables
            int startrow = 0, endrow = 0, startcol = 0, endcol = 0;
            int sumofred = 0, sumofgreen = 0, sumofblue = 0;
            float pixelscount = 0;
            int averagered = 0, averagegreen = 0, averageblue = 0;
            /**
             * determine the blur box limits
             * determine the start row and the end row from top to bottom
             * determine the strat column and end column from left to right
            */
            if (row == 0){
                startrow = row;
                endrow = row + 1;
            }

            else if (row == height - 1){
                startrow = row - 1;
                endrow = row;
            }
            else if ((row>0) && (row<height - 1)){
                startrow = row - 1;
                endrow = row + 1;
            }

            if (col == 0){
                startcol = col;
                endcol = col + 1;
            }
            else if (col == width - 1){
                startcol = col - 1;
                endcol = col;
            }
            else if ((col>0) && (col<width - 1)){
                startcol = col - 1;
                endcol = col + 1;
            }

            //iterate over the blur box pixels
            for (int i = startrow; i <= endrow; i++)
            {
                for (int j = startcol; j <= endcol; j++)
                {
                    sumofred += image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                    sumofgreen += image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                    sumofblue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                    pixelscount++;
                }
            }
            //calculate average
            averagered = round(sumofred / pixelscount);
            averagegreen = round(sumofgreen / pixelscount);
            averageblue = round(sumofblue / pixelscount);

            //assign the new color values to the current pixel
            image[row][col].rgbtRed = averagered;
            image[row][col].rgbtGreen = averagegreen;
            image[row][col].rgbtBlue = averageblue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why does it say that it correctly filtered but then show that expected is different from what it got? Shouldn't those messages say "incorrectly"?

Comment: You need to put the blurred values in a new array. Otherwise, after you update a pixel, you'll use the new value when blurring its neighbors.

Comment: @Barmar: It does not say the program correctly filtered. The test framework first announces the test being performed, “blur correctly filters middle pixel”, and then announces the results, “expected "127 140 149\n", not "145 160 169\n"”. It is crappy formatting, language, and design.

Comment: @Barmar: They do not need a whole new array, just one row plus one element of history.

Comment: Those test framework messages always confuse me. They're naming the test, not the result.

Comment: To debug a routine like this, create a very small image (a 2×2 image might suffice in this case, even though it is all corner pixels), fill it with random data, calculate the expected results by hand, and then compare them to the observed results. Then step through the program line by line to see where a wrong result is calculated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's possible to do it more efficiently, but for a beginner the easiest solution is to just use another array.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).